# jquery: menu disappear on scroll reappear hover/mouseover/out

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover, slidedown, slideup

Im trying to have a menu across the bottom of an endless scrolling page.  I have the gist of it here [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4CdFP/22/)     When you scroll I would like the menu to disappear and then reappear on a hover/mouseover,mouseout function. .  I just can't seem to get it to work perfectly.  If you play around with it you'll notice that when you scroll, then move the mouse over it it will come back.  But if you scroll with the mouse still over the area it will slide down, then up, then down, then up etc.  It seems to glitch the code and gets out of wack. On an actual wepage you have to reload it to get it to work again.

Can anyone offer some assistance with this?

thanks

html

```
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>             
      <div class = "width"></div><div id = "bar"></div>
```

css

```
     .width {
width:100%;
height:60px;
background-color:red;
background-image: url('{image:Background}');
position:fixed;
z-index:1;
bottom:0px;
text-align:center;
font:12px helvetica;
letter-spacing:2px;
text-transform:lowercase;
color:#0f0f0f;
line-height:20px;
}
#bar {
width:100%;
height:60px;
background-color:transparent;
bottom:0px;
position: fixed;
}
```

jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 10) {
        $(".width").stop(true, true).slideDown();
    } else {
        $(".width").slideUp();
    }
    $().ready(function () {
        $("#bar", this).mouseover(function () {
            $(".width").slideDown("slow");
        });
        $("#bar", this).mouseout(function () {
            $(".width").slideUp("slow");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your HTML to this:

```
<div id="bar">
    <div class="width">
        · <a href="http://itsdoom.com" target="new" style="target-name: new; target-new: tab;">website</a> ·  <a href="/rss">rss</a> ·
        <div id="tituli">
            <a href="http://everycornerlurksdoom.tumblr.com">DOOM</a>
        </div><!-- #tituli -->
    </div><!-- .width -->
</div><!-- #bar -->
```

EDIT** Let me know if this is what you're after:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.width').slideDown();
    hovered = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() { 
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 10 && hovered === false){
            $( ".width" ).slideUp();   
        } else if (hovered === true) { 
            $('.width').show();
        } else {
            $('.width').slideDown();
        }
    });
    $("#bar").mouseenter(function (e){
            if ($('.width').is(':visible') && hovered === false) {
                e.preventDefault();
                hovered = true;
            } else {
                $(".width").slideDown("slow");
                hovered = true;
            }
     });

     $("#bar").mouseleave(function (e){
         if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 10) {
             $(".width").slideUp("slow");
                 hovered = false;
         } else {
             e.preventDefault();
             hovered = false;
         }
     }); 
});
```

Here's a newer-er-er fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4CdFP/28/

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks.  thats close but it still does the same thing.  when you have the mouse in the outlined box and scroll, the solid red box goes up and down and up and down.   Im trying to get the solid red box to stay up, if the mouse is in the area, while scrolling.  Then it drops back down when the mouse is out of the area.  Basically putting the scroll function on hold while its doing the hover/mouseover function.   if that makes sense

Comment: I just updated my answer and linked to a new fiddle. Let me know if that's what you're after.

Comment: Oh, I also got rid of the `z-index` on `.width` because it was screwing with the hover functions.

Comment: Thats amazing.  Looks really complicated.   That is what I wanted and it works fantastic on the fiddle page, but when I implement it into the website (a tumblr) it does the same thing as before.  I have absolutely no idea why.

Comment: I am thoroughly confused

Comment: Your browser probably has a cached version of your old code. Try a hard refresh and see if that helps. Also, I'm about to update my answer again. The `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` functions should be OUTSIDE the scroll function.

Comment: It's not complicated. I'm just using the variable `hovered` to test whether the mouse has entered or left the footer, and if it's entered but not left we prevent the footer from sliding up on scroll.

Comment: hmm I never would have figured that out.  I tried the updated one in safari and chrome and its still doing the same thing.  It must be a problem with tumblr.    I thought it may have been because I have another div within the '.width'  (which is actually the menu) but it's still doing it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4CdFP/26/   thats how the html looks on the site. (minus the <br>)  and with tituli or whatever my friend has it named.  I tried doing inline css for tituli in the html and had the same problem.

Comment: The problem is in your HTML I believe. I'll add the updated code to my answer, minus the line breaks.

Comment: you're right.  I just saw it. My brain is fried, haha.  Thanks so much for your help, hope it wasn't too much trouble

Comment: Okay, I just posted the LAST edit. Somehow the hover functions got added back inside the scroll function in the fiddle, so I updated that. You want those functions outside or they will not get called the first time you hover if the window has not been scrolled. And no problem, by the way. That's why I'm here :)